# Text Fade Effect with Animate.css - unexplained behavior

Tags: javascript, css

The goal is to display some text (html) in a div tag with fade in/ fade out effect on mouse over/ out events triggered by another element(s).
I used the Animate.css solution and came across a multitude of problems, especially when the elements are hovered in a rapid succession.
When I tried to build a simpler model, without resorting to jQuery, unlike the original solution, one part of the code behavior is inexplicable to me - please see the below example. It works as expected, but if the following line `document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="animate.css has ended; was triggered by "+e.target.id+" on "+e.type+" event.";` is omitted, the events that triggered the animation function are not recognized and the text hides on mouseOver. As changing the innerHTML of an element to my understanding has nothing to do with an animationend event, hope someone can explain this code behavior.

```js
// (e), event is used to differentiate between mouseOver and mouseOut
function animate(e){
 // start mesage
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=e.target.id+" fired "+e.type+"; animate.css is starting...";
 // setting animation type based on the triggering event
 var animation = "animated fadeIn";
 if (e.type=="mouseout"){
 animation = "animated fadeOut";
 }
 // triggering animation by applying the animation classes
 document.getElementById("info").setAttribute("class", animation);
 // setting animation end callback
 this.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
 // end message. If the line below is commented, the message is deleted regardless of the event that fired it (it is expected to be deleted on mouseOut only)
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="animate.css has ended; was triggered by "+e.target.id+" on "+e.type+" event.";
 // removing (regenerating) the animation classes  
 document.getElementById("info").removeAttribute("class");
 // deletes the message on mouseOut 
 if (e.type=="mouseout"){
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="null";
 }
 });
} 

// all svg path elements will trigger the animate(event) function on mouseOver and mouseOut
var petals = document.querySelectorAll("path");
for(i=0;i<petals.length; i++){
//changes the default mouse cursor into a hand
petals[i].style="cursor: pointer;";
//mouseOver
petals[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function (event){
animate(event);
});
//mouseOut
petals[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function (event){
animate(event);
});
}
```

```css
<style>
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
#info {
 height: 15%;
 /* background-color: darkgreen;
 color: gainsboro;*/
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 5.5vh;
 padding: 2%;
}
/* animate.css: */
.animated {
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.fadeOut {
 animation-duration: 3s;
}
 @keyframes fadeOut {
 from {
 opacity: 1;
}
 to {
 opacity: 0;
}
}
.fadeOut {
 animation-name: fadeOut;
}
 @keyframes fadeIn {
 from {
 opacity: 0;
}
 to {
 opacity: 1;
}
}
.fadeIn {
 animation-name: fadeIn;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="info"> info </div>
<div style="height: 70%; background-color:papayawhip; padding: 1.5%;">
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 318.3 258.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 318.3 258.1;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
.darkred{
fill: darkred;
stroke-width: 1;
}
.darkred:hover{
fill: red;
stroke: black;
}
.red{
fill: red;
}
.red:hover {
fill: orange;
stroke: black;
}
.orange{
fill: orange;
}
.orange:hover {
fill: yellow;
stroke: black;
}

</style>
  <path id="petal-1" class="darkred" d="M159.1,1c53.3,42.7,53.3,85.3,0,128V1z"/>
  <path id="petal-2" class="orange" d="M213.8,8.8c31.9,54.7,13.6,94.8-54.7,120.3L213.8,8.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-3" class="red" d="M262,31c6.6,60.1-27.7,92.8-102.8,98.1L262,31z"/>
  <path id="petal-4" class="darkred" d="M297.7,65c-19.5,58.3-65.7,79.6-138.6,64L297.7,65z"/>
  <path id="petal-5" class="orange" d="M316.7,106.8c-43.3,49.4-95.8,56.8-157.6,22.2L316.7,106.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-6" class="red" d="M316.7,151.3c-61.8,34.6-114.3,27.2-157.6-22.2L316.7,151.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-7" class="darkred" d="M297.7,193c-72.9,15.6-119-5.7-138.6-64L297.7,193z"/>
  <path id="petal-8" class="orange" d="M262,227.1c-75.1-5.3-109.4-37.9-102.8-98.1L262,227.1z"/>
  <path id="petal-9" class="red" d="M213.8,249.3c-68.4-25.5-86.6-65.6-54.7-120.3L213.8,249.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-10" class="darkred" d="M159.1,257c-53.3-42.7-53.3-85.3,0-128V257z"/>
  <path id="petal-11" class="orange" d="M104.4,249.3c-31.9-54.7-13.6-94.8,54.7-120.3L104.4,249.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-12" class="red" d="M56.3,227.1C49.7,167,84,134.3,159.1,129L56.3,227.1z"/>
  <path id="petal-13" class="darkred" d="M20.5,193c19.5-58.3,65.7-79.6,138.6-64L20.5,193z"/>
  <path id="petal-14" class="orange" d="M1.5,151.3c43.3-49.4,95.8-56.8,157.6-22.2L1.5,151.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-15" class="red" d="M1.5,106.8C63.3,72.2,115.8,79.6,159.1,129L1.5,106.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-16" class="darkred" d="M20.5,65c72.9-15.6,119,5.7,138.6,64L20.5,65z"/>
  <path id="petal-17" class="orange" d="M56.3,31c75.1,5.3,109.4,37.9,102.8,98.1L56.3,31z"/>
  <path id="petal-18" class="red" d="M104.4,8.8C172.7,34.3,191,74.4,159.1,129L104.4,8.8z"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing is not caused by events not being recognized, but rather because of the order in which the callback functions are being executed.

Let me try to explain this...

When you comment out the line `document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="animate.css has ended; was triggered by "+e.target.id+" on "+e.type+" event.";`, this is what you get:

### The Setup

For every `mouseover` and `mouseout` event, you are calling **two** functions:

1. `animate(e)`, which displays some text in the div, and starts the animation.
2. Anonymous `function()` executed on `animationend`, which will check if `e.type == 'mouseout'`.  If it is, it will change the text in the div to 'null', otherwise, it will not change the text at all.  (If you comment out the line mentioned above.)

**However**, and this is important, the first function is called as soon as the event is triggered, and the second one is a callback function that is called only after the animation has ended.

### Hovering over elements in rapid succession

When you hover over petal A, and jump quickly to petal B, you may not have realize, but there are actually **three** events happening:

1. There was a `mouseover` event on petal A
2. There was a `mouseout` event on petal A
3. There was `mouseovoer` event on petal B

Each of these events, will end up calling two functions, however, since the second function is only called once the animation is complete, the functions are executed in the following order:

1. `mouseover`(petal A) calls `animate(e)`
2. `mouseout`(petal A) calls `aminate(e)`
3. `mouseover`(petal B) calls `animate(e)`
4. `animationend` from `mouseover`(petal A) calls anonymous `function()`
5. `animationend` from `mouseout`(petal A) calls anonymous `function()`
6. `animationend` from `mouseover`(petal B) calls anonymous `function()`

**Let's examine how this effects the text in the div:**

- At **step 1-3** the div will display the event target id, event type, and 'animate.css is starting...'.
- At **step 4** nothing in the div will change, since the event type is `mouseover`.  The div will continue to display the event target id, event type, and 'animate.css is starting...', as expected.
- At **step 5** the text in the div will change to 'null', because the animation was triggered by a `mouseout` event.
- At **step 6**, again, nothing in the div will change, since the event type is `mouseover`.  So the div will continue to display 'null'...

### Proof of Concept

To prove this, you can either add the event target id to the text, and you will see that it was the previous petal that caused 'null' to be displayed, and not the petal you are currently hovering over.  Or, use `if {} else {}`, to change the text in the div on `animationend` if `e.type` does not equal `mouseout`, and you'll see that there is no confusion here over which event it was.

```
if (e.type=="mouseout"){
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="null " + e.target.id;
} else {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="This is the animationend of a " + e.type + " event";
}
```

### *Important Note:*

An event listener that is added to the DOM is not removed, unless you explicitly remove it, or add it with the `once: true` option.

Since you are adding an event listener to listen for `animationend` on every `mouseover` and `mouseout` event, without ever removing it, you will end up with dozens of event listeners triggering the same callback function on `animationend`.

This can be easily fixed by adding the `once: true` option as an argument to `addEventListener()`.  This will automatically remove the listener as soon as the callback function is invoked.

```
function animate(e){

    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=e.target.id+" fired "+e.type+"; animate.css is starting...";

    var animation = "animated fadeIn";
    if (e.type=="mouseout"){
        animation = "animated fadeOut";
    }       
    document.getElementById("info").setAttribute("class", animation);

    this.addEventListener("animationend", function() {                  
        document.getElementById("info").removeAttribute("class");

        if (e.type=="mouseout"){
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="null ";
        }

    }, {once: true}); // Add this option to automatically remove event listener once invoked
}
```

Comment: Chava G, thank you so much for taking your time and analyzing in detail how the code is implemented. After racking my brains out I think I got the idea. This also might explain why this code is working

Answer (score 0):

Chava G, thank you so much for taking your time and analyzing in detail how the code is implemented. After racking my brains out I think I got the idea...

I was aware of the "once" option of the addEventListener method, but did not know how to implement it. I had no idea that identical event listeners were appended instead of replaced and that explains the performance issues and some messages of code repetition in the developer tools that I did not know how to address. Besides in this.addEventListener("animationend", function()) this seems to refer to the window object...

How about attaching the animationend event only once to the info div and not trying to remove it? By the way if the alternating animations have different names, e.g. animationIn and animationOut, the animationend event that clears the animation class is not necessary, as illustrated in the below version of the project. In Firefox however, the mouseover animation is applied just once when hovering over multiple elements, while in IE, every element is animated. Is this a browser specific issue, or something again is wrong with my coding?

```js
// (e), event is used to differentiate between mouseOver and mouseOut
function animate(e){
 
 // start mesage
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=e.target.id+" fired "+e.type+"; animate.css is starting...";
 // setting animation type based on the triggering event
 var animation = "animated ";
 if (e.type=="mouseout"){
 animation += animationOut;
 }
 else{
 animation += animationIn; 
 }
 // triggering animation by applying the animation classes
 document.getElementById("info").setAttribute("class", animation);

}
 
// all svg path elements will trigger the animate(event) function on mouseOver and mouseOut
var petals = document.querySelectorAll("path");
for(i=0;i<petals.length; i++){
//changes the default mouse cursor into a hand
petals[i].setAttribute("style", "cursor: pointer;");
//mouseOver
petals[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function (event){
animate(event);
});
//mouseOut
petals[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function (event){
animate(event);
});
}
```

```css
html, body {
 font-family: monospace;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
#container-info {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#info {
 height: 10%;
 /* background-color: darkgreen;
 color: gainsboro;*/
 font-size: 5.5vmin;
 padding: 2%;
}
#blossom {
 height: 65%;
 background-color: papayawhip;
 padding: 1.5%;
}
.transitions-menu {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.5%;
 background-color: papayawhip;
 font-size: 2vw;
 color: darkred;
 border: 1px solid darkred;
}
select {
 background-color: BurlyWood;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<div class="transitions-menu">animationIn =
 <select onchange = "animationIn = this.value; animationOut = animationIn.replace(/In/i, 'Out'); document.getElementsByName('out')[0].selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;">
<script type="text/javascript">  
var animationIn = "fadeIn"; 
animations = [
"bounceIn",
"bounceInDown",
"bounceInLeft",
"bounceInRight",
"bounceInUp",
"fadeIn",
"fadeInDown",
"fadeInDownBig",
"fadeInLeft",
"fadeInLeftBig",
"fadeInRight",
"fadeInRightBig",
"fadeInUp",
"fadeInUpBig",
"flipInX",
"flipInY",
"lightSpeedIn",
"rollIn",
"rotateIn",
"rotateInDownLeft",
"rotateInDownRight",
"rotateInUpLeft",
"rotateInUpRight",
"slideInDown",
"slideInLeft",
"slideInRight",
"slideInUp",
"zoomIn",
"zoomInDown",
"zoomInLeft",
"zoomInRight",
"zoomInUp",
//////////////////////////////////////  
"bounce",
"flash",
"headShake",
"hinge",
// has no Out equivalent "jackInTheBox",
"jello",
"pulse",
"rubberBand",
"shake",
"swing",
"tada",
"wobble"
];
for (i=0; i<animations.length;i++){
 if (animations[i] != animationIn){
 document.write('<option value="' + animations[i]+ '">' + animations[i]+ '</option>\n');
 }
 else {
 document.write('<option value="' + animations[i]+ '" selected>' + animations[i]+ '</option>\n'); 
 }
}
</script>
</select>
</div>
<div class="transitions-menu">animationOut =
<select name="out" onchange = "animationOut = this.value">
<script type="text/javascript">  
// var animationOut = "fadeOutRight"; 
var animationOut = animationIn.replace(/In/, "Out");

for (i=0; i<animations.length;i++){
var optName = animations[i].replace(/In/, "Out"); 
 if (animations[i] != animationIn){
 document.write('<option value="' + optName + '">' + optName + '</option>\n');
 }
 else {
 document.write('<option value="' + optName + '" selected>' + optName + '</option>\n'); 
 }
}
</script>
</select>
</div>

<div id="container-info">
 <div id="info"> info </div>
</div>

<div id="blossom">
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 318.3 258.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 318.3 258.1;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
.darkred{
fill: darkred;
stroke-width: 1;
}
.darkred:hover{
fill: red;
stroke: black;
}
.red{
fill: red;
}
.red:hover {
fill: orange;
stroke: black;
}
.orange{
fill: orange;
}
.orange:hover {
fill: yellow;
stroke: black;
}

</style>
  <path id="petal-1" class="darkred" d="M159.1,1c53.3,42.7,53.3,85.3,0,128V1z"/>
  <path id="petal-2" class="orange" d="M213.8,8.8c31.9,54.7,13.6,94.8-54.7,120.3L213.8,8.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-3" class="red" d="M262,31c6.6,60.1-27.7,92.8-102.8,98.1L262,31z"/>
  <path id="petal-4" class="darkred" d="M297.7,65c-19.5,58.3-65.7,79.6-138.6,64L297.7,65z"/>
  <path id="petal-5" class="orange" d="M316.7,106.8c-43.3,49.4-95.8,56.8-157.6,22.2L316.7,106.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-6" class="red" d="M316.7,151.3c-61.8,34.6-114.3,27.2-157.6-22.2L316.7,151.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-7" class="darkred" d="M297.7,193c-72.9,15.6-119-5.7-138.6-64L297.7,193z"/>
  <path id="petal-8" class="orange" d="M262,227.1c-75.1-5.3-109.4-37.9-102.8-98.1L262,227.1z"/>
  <path id="petal-9" class="red" d="M213.8,249.3c-68.4-25.5-86.6-65.6-54.7-120.3L213.8,249.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-10" class="darkred" d="M159.1,257c-53.3-42.7-53.3-85.3,0-128V257z"/>
  <path id="petal-11" class="orange" d="M104.4,249.3c-31.9-54.7-13.6-94.8,54.7-120.3L104.4,249.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-12" class="red" d="M56.3,227.1C49.7,167,84,134.3,159.1,129L56.3,227.1z"/>
  <path id="petal-13" class="darkred" d="M20.5,193c19.5-58.3,65.7-79.6,138.6-64L20.5,193z"/>
  <path id="petal-14" class="orange" d="M1.5,151.3c43.3-49.4,95.8-56.8,157.6-22.2L1.5,151.3z"/>
  <path id="petal-15" class="red" d="M1.5,106.8C63.3,72.2,115.8,79.6,159.1,129L1.5,106.8z"/>
  <path id="petal-16" class="darkred" d="M20.5,65c72.9-15.6,119,5.7,138.6,64L20.5,65z"/>
  <path id="petal-17" class="orange" d="M56.3,31c75.1,5.3,109.4,37.9,102.8,98.1L56.3,31z"/>
  <path id="petal-18" class="red" d="M104.4,8.8C172.7,34.3,191,74.4,159.1,129L104.4,8.8z"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```